# Input and output type mismatch in Combine data fetching

Tags: ios, swift, reactive-programming, combine, flatmap

I am new to reactive programming and Combine, I have the following method which fetching the weather Data from the API.

- First, I am checking that if I get 200 if not then throw an error.
- If I get the proper data I am decoding it via JSONDecoder but just to
  check if there is some problem JSON decoding I am returning the default Object.
- Finally mapping the error which is thrown in the
  first step but I am getting the following error in flatMAp function
  instance method

**flatMap(maxPublishers:_:)' requires the types 'Publishers.TryMap.Failure' (aka 'Error') and 'Just.Failure' (aka 'Never') be equivalent**

```
private func fetchDataFor(urlStr: String) -> AnyPublisher<WeatherData, Error> {
            let url = URL(string: urlStr)!
            return URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: url)
                .tryMap({ (data, response)  in
                    let response = (response as? HTTPURLResponse)
                    if response?.statusCode != 200 {
                        throw NSError(domain: "Error", code: response!.statusCode, userInfo: .none)
                    }
                    return data
            })
            .flatMap{ data in
                Just(data)
                    .decode(type: WeatherData.self, decoder: JSONDecoder())
                    .catch{ error in
                        return Just(defaultWeatherData)
                    }
            }
            .mapError{ error in
                return error
            }
            .receive(on: RunLoop.main)
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
        }
```

Can somebody guide what is wrong here or I am using some wrong approach. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Change your function to this:

```
private func fetchDataFor(urlStr: String) -> AnyPublisher<WeatherData, Error> {
    let url = URL(string: urlStr)!
    return URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: url)
        .tryMap({ (data, response)  in
            let response = (response as? HTTPURLResponse)
            if response?.statusCode != 200 {
                throw NSError(domain: "Error", code: response!.statusCode, userInfo: .none)
            }
            return data
        })
        .decode(type: WeatherData.self, decoder: JSONDecoder())
        .receive(on: RunLoop.main)
        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
}
```

**Combine** has helpful build-in `.decode` method, where you can convert your data to the local model.

Also, a good practice is not to use `.receive(on: RunLoop.main)` in the request methods, but let your ViewModel/Interactor (simply a consumer of response) decide on which thread it wants to receive the response.

Comment: Hi thanks, actually I had this implementation before I anted to check if there is some parsing issue during JSON parsing then I want to get the default object. Keep that in mind I wrote the function ith flatmap

Comment: Also, this mapError corresponds to FlatMap or to tryMap or any error that has happened in the events chain.

Comment: That you can replace your flatMap with this one:
    .flatMap { data in
        Just(data).decode(type: WeatherData.self, decoder: JSONDecoder())
            .catch { error in
                return Just(defaultWeatherData)
                    .setFailureType(to: Error.self)
                    .eraseToAnyPublisher()
        }
}